# Numeration System suppose it takes a clock one minute to strike 15 times at regular intervals

Tags: arithmetic

suppose it takes a clock one minute to strike 15 times at regular intervals.
How long will it take for this clock to strike 2019 times?

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like this that look like routine homework problems and which show no effort at all.  What have you tried?  With problems like this, it's easy to get lost in the details of the arithmetic, but you ought to be able to at least try something.  Please edit your post to include your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

1. If the clock strikes twice, how many intervals are there between the first and last strike?
2. If the clock strikes three times, how many intervals are there between the first and last strike?
3. If the clock strikes four times, how many intervals are there between the first and last strike?
4. Now you should be able to say how many intervals there are between the first and last strike if it strikes 15 times.
5. If that many intervals make one minute, how long is each interval?
6. How many intervals are there if the clock strikes 2019 times?
7. Now you should be able to say how long this takes, knowing (a) the length of each interval and (b) the number of intervals for 2019 strikes.

Answer (score -1):

There are 60 seconds in a minute so if a clock strikes 15 times in a minute, it strikes every 60/15= 4 seconds.  But, or course, the time starts only after the first strike!  So, ignoring the time during the strike, 6 strikes will take 5(4)= 20 seconds.